How do you link to the uploaded file to an Assessment Question Response of data type File?
I want to link the uploaded file for this AssessmentQuestionResponse. In the Response Value field is the ContentDocumentId
I tried using the AssessmentQuestionResponseId as the LinkedEntityId to narrow it down, but I'm not getting any results.
I have successfully linked uploaded files to the record they're related to in the past by following this guide: https://driveconnect.me/blog/contentdocument-contentversion-and-contentdocumentlink/. But I'm hitting a roadblock in this scenario
